# Openui5 ux3.Shell - content not displayed after click on navbar item

Tags: sapui5

I'm a beginner in openui5 programming. I tried some tutorial but now I have some troubles regarding ux3.shell. What  want is quit simple, but I'm not able to fix my problem. I will have a menu bar in the top and will display content after click on the menu item.

Here is my coding ( I will paste more than needed, because in this time, I have no idea, where the problem is located:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Stall</title>

    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="../../resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
        data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
        data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"com.sp": ""}'>
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <script>
        sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
            new sap.m.Shell({
                app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                    height : "100%",
                    name : "com.sp"
                })
            }).placeAt("content");
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

component.js

```
sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
"sap/ui/Device",
"com/sp/model/models"
], function(UIComponent, Device, models) {
"use strict";

return UIComponent.extend("com.sp.Component", {

    metadata: {
        manifest: "json"
    },

    init: function() {
        // call the base component's init function
        UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

        // set the device model
        this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");
      var oView = sap.ui.view({
        id: "MainViewShell",
        viewName: "com.sp.view.MainView",
        type: "XML",
        viewData: { component : this }
    });

    // set i18n model
    var i18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
        bundleUrl : "i18n/messageBundle.properties"
    });
    oView.setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");

    // done
    return oView;        

    }
  });
});
```

MainView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<mvc:View controllerName="com.sp.controller.MainView"      displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
<App id="idMainView">
    <mvc:XMLView viewName="com.sp.view.ShellView" id="idShellView" />
</App>
</mvc:View>
```

MainView controller

```
sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller) {
"use strict";

return Controller.extend("com.sp.controller.MainView", {


onInit: function(oEvent) {

    this.oApp = this.getView().byId("idMainView");

    // Have child views use this controller for navigation
    var that = this;
    this.oApp.getPages().forEach(function(oPage) {
        oPage.getController().navigation = that;
    });

},
navTo: function(sPageId, oContext) {

    this.oApp.to(sPageId);
    if (oContext) {
        this.oApp.getPage(sPageId).setBindingContext(oContext);
    }

},
navBack: function() {

    this.oApp.back();

} 
});
});
```

ShellView

```
<mvc:View controllerName="com.sp.controller.ShellView" 
      xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:ux3="sap.ui.ux3"  
      xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
      xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
      xmlns="sap.m">
<App>
    <pages>
<ux3:Shell id="idShellView" appTitle="Stall" worksetItemSelected="onNavigate">

    <ux3:worksetItems>

        <ux3:NavigationItem text="Seite1" key="key1">
        </ux3:NavigationItem>

        <ux3:NavigationItem text="Seite2" key="key2">
        </ux3:NavigationItem>

    </ux3:worksetItems>

    <ux3:content>
            <mvc:XMLView viewName="com.sp.view.TempView" id="idTempView" />
    </ux3:content>

</ux3:Shell>

    </pages>
</App>
</mvc:View>
```

ShellView Controller

```
sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller) {
"use strict";

return Controller.extend("com.sp.controller.ShellView", {


onNavigate:function(evt){

    switch(evt.getParameter("key")){
        case "key1":
            this.getView().byId("idShellView").setContent(sap.ui.xmlview("com.sp.view.OverviewView"));
            break;
        case "key2":
            this.getView().byId("idShellView").setContent(sap.ui.xmlview("com.sp.view.TempView"));
            break;
        default:
            this.getView().byId("idShellView").setContent(sap.ui.xmlview("com.sp.view.TempView"));
    }

},      
    buttonPress: function() {

        alert(this.getView().valueOf(name) );
        }   

});

});
```

The views TempView and OverviewView are nearly the same, filled only with a small textfield, but they never will be displayed. Sometimes it looks like, that the are displayed "under" shell view (short blinking).

For me is really strange, if I add in the ShellView controller this under the switch statement:

```
this.placeAt("content");
```

It will give a error "Uncaught TypeError: this.placeAt is not a function", but the content will be displayed.

Does anyone have an idea and could help me?

Many thanks in advance Stefan

Answer (score 1):

In your Controller function, `this` is a reference to the Controller instance which doesn't have a `placeAt` method as it does not get displayed itself.

In any case `placeAt` places a SAPUI5 *Control* in a *DOM-Element* defined by the given id. In your application you should **only use it once** in your `index.html`. For adding Controls (or Views) later, you should use the Aggregations that the Controls provide.

To add the initial View to the Page your Component has to provide the `createContent` method instead of returning it in `init`.

See [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PfIBzx?p=preview) for a working example based on your code. I modified it a bit by removing the MainView, and loading OverviewView as default content of your Shell.

Answer (score 0):

can you try to add  libs after "sap.m" like

"sap.m , sap.ui.ux3"

becuase shell belongs to sap.ui.ux3